# Difference between list.pop() and list = list[:-1]

Tags: python, list

```
>>> a = [1,2,3]
>>> a.pop()
3
>>> a
[1, 2]
>>> a = [1,2,3]
>>> a = a[:-1]
>>> a
[1, 2]
>>>
```

Is there any difference between the above methods to remove the last element from a list?

Comment: Yes, using `pop` modifies the list being referenced by `a` in-place in constant timw, whereas using the slice creates a new list and assigns that to `a` and works in linear time

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes. `pop` is O(1) and mutates the original list, while slice is O(n) and creates a copy of the list. Less formally, the [`pop`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/b7aa23d29fa48238dab3692d02e1f0a7e8a5af9c/Objects/listobject.c#L1014) method is an operation on the element at the end of the list and is defined in CPython as a call to `list_resize(self, Py_SIZE(self) - 1);`. This doesn't traverse the entire structure.

On the other hand, [`list_slice`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/b7aa23d29fa48238dab3692d02e1f0a7e8a5af9c/Objects/listobject.c#L449) allocates a new list and loops over the entries in the old list ranging from the beginning to the end - 1, copying references to each item to the new list.

If what you're trying to do is remove the last element of the list, use `pop` or `del a[-1]`.

Comment: `pop` can accept one index param, such as `pop(0)`, in this case, is it still `O(1)`?

Comment: Good question. No--`pop` is traditionally an O(1) operation on the "top" or back/right of a stack data structure. Lists in Python give `pop` an extra parameter to enable it to work on the middle, but the rest of the elements in the list need to by shifted forward to fill in the gap, O(n). Check the source code for the full story. There is a conditional that switches between `pop()` and `pop(n)`--the latter calls `list_ass_slice(self, index, index+1, (PyObject *)NULL);` which performs the shift-forward operation on the list. If you're using `pop(0)` frequently, look into `collections.deque`.

Comment: Actually, if all you want to do is remove the last element of the `list`, `del mylist[-1]` is the way to go. You use `pop` when you want to remove the last element from the `list` *and* keep the value (which `pop` returns). `del mylist[-1]` has the same big O behaviors as `pop`, and it's directly syntax/bytecode supported, which is typically faster than function calls (though modern versions of CPython have been narrowing the gap by speeding up simple method calls).

Answer (score 3):

`pop` do not change the id, just pop one item of list.

`[:-1]` is slice operation, which create a new list from old list.

```
>>> a = [1,2,3]
print(id(a))
>>> a.pop()
3
print(id(a))
>>> a
[1, 2]
>>> a = [1,2,3]
>>> a = a[:-1]
>>> a
print(id(a))
[1, 2]
>>>
```

id output (the number is not important, same or not same is key point):

```
4470627464
4470627464
4474450952
```

Comment: notably, because `pop` mutates the list being referenced by `a` while the slice operation updates `a` to reference a new list, the primary difference arises when some other variable has a reference to the same list

Answer (score 1):

the **pop** method returns the last item from the list that it removes.
for example:

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
b = a.pop()
print(b)  # 4
```

Also, using slicing, you are making a copy of the old list, whereas with using **pop** the list reference remains the same.

Answer (score 1):

There is an basic difference thats occurs using in functions . Using`[:-1]` unchanged the original list but `pop()` can do.

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [1,2,3]


def functionb(list):
    list = list[:-1]
    return list
def withpop(list):
    return list.pop()

functionb(b)
withpop(a)
print b
print a
```

Will printed:

```
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 2]
```

Second is execution time . `pop()` is faster than `[:-1]` Because when you use `[:-1]`you have to overwrite to list.Lets say you have thousands values in index so it will be slowly than `pop()`

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is difference.
when you use a.pop() you remove from list too
when you use a[:-1] object list not change
check with len(a)

```
>>> a = [1,2,3]
>>> a
[1, 2, 3]
>>> a[:-1]
[1, 2]
>>> len(a[:-1])
2
>>> a.pop()
3
>>> a
[1, 2]
>>> len(a)
2
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you have presented them, there's no outward difference.  The `pop` instruction gives the interpreter an easier time of optimizing the instruction, as it can merely decrement the length attribute of the list.  The `-1` assignment will construct a new list, assign that to `a`, and then leave the old one for garbage collection.

There is a huge difference in aliasing: if you assigned something else to that list, you will get side effects with `pop`.  For instance:

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> b = a
>>> b
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> a.pop()
4
>>> b
[1, 2, 3]
>>> a = a[:-1]
>>> b
[1, 2, 3]
>>> a
[1, 2]
```

Comment: Mind you, the slice can also perform those same side-effects if needed, by changing `a = a[:-1]` to `a[:] = a[:-1]`; instead of rebinding `a` to a new `list`, assigning to the "empty" slice replace the *contents* of the original `list` with the results of the slice.