# Why get different results, when using list.pop() and list = list[:-1] in recursive problem

Tags: python, list, recursion

I am trying to use a recursive method to solve the ["Combination Sum"](https://leetcode.com/problems/combination-sum/) problem on Leetcode.

> Combination Sum Problem
>
> 1. Given an array of **distinct** integers `candidates` and a target integer `target`, return *a list of all **unique combinations** of* `candidates`*where the chosen numbers sum to* `target`*.* You may return the combinations in **any order**.
> 2. The **same** number may be chosen from `candidates` an **unlimited number of times**. Two combinations are unique if the frequency of at least one of the chosen numbers is different.
>    Example
>
> ```
> Input: candidates = [2,3,5], target = 8
> Output: [[2,2,2,2],[2,3,3],[3,5]]
> ```

When I use "c = c[:-1]" to get rid of the end element of "c", I cannot get the right result. However, after I replaced "c = c[:-1]" with "c.pop()", the result get right.

After reading [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56711615/difference-between-list-pop-and-list-list-1), my understanding is

1. "list.pop()" will make a change on the original list, whereas "list[:-1]" will create a new list.
2. "list.pop()" and "list=list[:-1]" will get the same result

**But in my recursive method, clearly, "list=list[:-1]" didn't get the job done. I am wondering why there is a difference between "list.pop" and "list=list[:-1]" in a recursive function. Why list=list[:-1] will make mistake in the recursive method?**

Here is my code:

```py
"""
def findCombination(self, nums: List[int], target: int,
                    index: int, c: List[int],
                    res: List[List[int]]):
"""
def findCombination(nums, target, index, c, res):
    if target <= 0:
        if target == 0:
            res.append(c.copy())
        return
    for i in range(index, len(nums)):
        if nums[i] > target:
            break
        c.append(nums[i])
        print(f"self.findCombination({nums}, {target - nums[i]}, {i}, {c}, {res})")
        findCombination(nums, target - nums[i], i, c, res)
        c.pop()
        # c = c[:-1]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    candidates = [2, 3, 5]
    target = 5
    c, res = [], []
    findCombination(candidates, target, 0, c, res)
    print(f"Combinations: {res}")
"""
Using c.pop()
---------------------
self.findCombination([2, 3, 5], 3, 0, [2], [])
self.findCombination([2, 3, 5], 1, 0, [2, 2], [])
self.findCombination([2, 3, 5], 0, 1, [2, 3], [])
self.findCombination([2, 3, 5], 2, 1, [3], [[2, 3]])
self.findCombination([2, 3, 5], 0, 2, [5], [[2, 3]])
Combinations: [[2, 3], [5]]

Using c = c[:-1]
---------------------
self.findCombination([2, 3, 5], 3, 0, [2], [])
self.findCombination([2, 3, 5], 1, 0, [2, 2], [])
self.findCombination([2, 3, 5], 0, 1, [2, 3], [])
self.findCombination([2, 3, 5], 2, 1, [2, 3], [[2, 3]]) # Here, mistask, 2 didn't be popped
self.findCombination([2, 3, 5], 0, 2, [2, 5], [[2, 3]])
Combinations: [[2, 3], [2, 5]]
"""
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python function arguments are passed by reference and all variables are just references to actual objects in memory.

```
list.pop()
```

changes the object the reference is pointing to.

```
list=list[:-1]
```

redirects the reference to a new object. It doesn't affect the object outside the function.

Remember that `=` always redirects the reference.

```
a = [1] # reference to new object
b = a # reference to a
b.pop() # this changes a through b
print(a)
b = [1] # reference to new object, doesn't affect a anymore
print(a)
```

Output:

```
[]
[]
```

This example code highlights the difference using functions

```
a = [1]
b = [1]

def f1(v):
    v.pop()
    print(v)
    # v is still a reference to a
    
def f2(v):
    # v is a reference to b
    v = v[:-1]
    # v is now a reference to a new object
    print(v)
    
print(a)
f1(a)
print(a)

print(b)
f2(b)
print(b)
```

Output:

```
[1]
[]
[]
[1]
[]
[1]
```

To be correct: `b` is not a reference to `a` and `v` is not a reference to `a` or `b`. They all are reference to same objects in memory. `b` doesn't change `a`. `b` changes the object `a` is pointing to.